# How do I migrate from SQL Server to PostgreSQL using flyway?

Tags: flyway

Hi I have source SQL DB and destination RDS PostgreSQL DB.
I want to migrate by using flyway. First is it possible ?
If possible then can anybody help me with solutions?

Comment: As Flyway uses plain SQL scripts (and not some DBMS independent format) you will have to rewrite/migrate each SQL script and adjust the syntax for Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Flyway is a tool for running scripts, rollbacks, targeted piecemeal deployments, all sorts of other stuff. However, it doesn't generate scripts. You have to provide it with syntax appropriate to the database system you're deploying to. T-SQL isn't the same as PostgreSQL. Nothing in Flyway will allow you to translate the T-SQL. You will have to do that work on your own. Once completed though, Flyway will absolutely be able to deploy those changes to your new database.